# Heteroskedasticity and skewness in regression, "in general"

Tags: regression, linear-model, lasso, elastic-net, regularization

In [another question of mine](http://kurt.schmidheiny.name/teaching/heteroscedasticity2up.pdf), I asked about fitting linear models based on the second-order Taylor expansion:
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \sum_i \beta_i (X_i - x_{0i}) + \sum_{i,j} \beta_{i,j} (X_i - x_{0i})(X_j - x_{0j}) + \left( \sigma + \sum_i \gamma_i (X_i - x_{0i}) \right) Z + \delta Z^2
$$

This model was not meant to be taken as something to be estimated explicitly. Rather, it was the basis for the recommendation that, when one is using regression to estimate a local curve, one ought to model conditional heteroskedasticity and skewness in the response variable.

Is there a general framework for this? FGLS (which I've never used and never had the chance to study) [seems like it would be the right approach for reasonably general modeling of heteroskedasticity](http://kurt.schmidheiny.name/teaching/heteroscedasticity2up.pdf), but what about skewness?